# MIPS: Encoding simple array into machine code

Tags: assembly, mips

I am using a 32-bit single cycle datapath simulator using Xilinx that can process MIPS code. I need to manually store array values in memory. Assuming I have an array that has the values 1,2, and 3 in it. How can I store it in memory by enconding it to 32-bit instructions, in which I can later load using the 'lw' instructions?

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to encode data by encoding an instruction whose value yields the data you want to store. Is that what you meant ? If the contents of the array are known in advance you should put the data directly

Comment: you just need to get register, put in it some data and then increment your register by number of bytes which you will store there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am trying to put the array contents directly into memory using machine code so I can later load them using 'lw'. However, I am confused as to how I can do this...

Comment: Are there no data declaration directives?